# Detecting taps in uiimageview inside uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiimageview

I have a UIScrollView with multiple UIImageViews in it created like this.

```
frame = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bg];
frame.frame = CGRectMake(FRAME_SEPARATOR + numPage*1024 + numColumn*(FRAME_SEPARATOR+230), 10 +numRow*(FRAME_SEPARATOR+145), 230, 145);
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
[frame addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];
[scroll addSubView:frame];
```

The problem is that imageTapped is not being called when tapping over an image.

If I add the gesture recognizer to the scrollview like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
[scroll addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];
```

imageTapped is called.

How can I detect the taps over the UIImageViews?

Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Make sure userInteractionEnabled is set to YES on the UIImageView:

```
frame.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

I'd also recommend using a different name for the UIImageView variable (eg. imageView instead of frame).  Otherwise, you can easily confuse it with the view's frame property.